# Error:- '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, file-handling, bisection

I have written a code to find the roots of an equation by bisection method.
I am trying to append my loop index and the difference between two solutions every iteration of the loop, but I am getting the error mentioned in the title of the question.

Also, I saw the answers to similar questions where people had already suggested to use the write method instead of calling it directly however, that just gives me an error saying that
`'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'write'`

My code:-

```
#Function to solve by bisection method
def bisection(f,a,b,fileName,tol = 10**-6):
    #making sure a is left of b
    if(a>b):
        temp = b
        b = a
        a = temp
    
    #Bracketing the roots
    a,b = bracketChecker(f,a,b)
    if((a,b) == False): return None

    #Checking if either of a or b is a root
    if(f(a)*f(b) == 0):
        if(f(a)==0):
            return a
        else: return b

    else:
        i = 0
        c = 0
        while(abs(a-b) > tol and i<200):
            c_old = c
            c = (a+b)/2.0
            abserr = c - c_old
            if (abs(f(c)) < tol):
                return c
            if (f(a)*f(c)<0):
                b = c
            else: a = c

            #Appending the data
            with open(fileName, 'a') as f:
                print(i,abserr, file=f)             #The error is occuring here
            i += 1
    return (a+b)/2.0
```

Comment: Hey, I can not reproduce your error but I notice you redefine variable "f". At first f is function passed to your arguments, then, f is a file object created by the open() function. Maybe, the line "print(i,abserr, file=f)" refer to the wrong f which is a built-in function ==> Python report the error 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'write'. I suggest you can try rename your variable and see what happen?

Comment: Yeah, i am stupid.
Thanx for pointing that out....
Changing f to something else works lmao...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine, the problem was only occurring because i had named the file as f, which is the same variable i used for my function. Hence, the errors...
Thank you @mibu for pointing that out

Comment: I am quite curious, why Python throw the error in the first place. Although you redefine your variable, variable redefinition is legal in Python (not a good practice though). So after line "with open(fileName, 'a') as f:", f should refer to the new file object not the old function => the line "print(i,abserr, file=f)" should not throw any error. What do you think?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm new to python so i dont really know....

Comment: FYI, I try your code myself and it work just fine.